# Design pattern for enum combination (method parameters)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, enums

I have a block of code similar to this one:

```
public bool DoMyThings(EnumRootAction root, EnumChildAction child){
          switch(root){
               case EnumRootAction.Type1:
                                switch(child){
                                       case EnumChildAction.Ac1: 
                                                    // DO something
                                                    break;
                                        case EnumChildAction.Ac2: 
                                                    // DO something
                                                    break;
                                        default: // child is not child of type root
                                                return false;
                                }
                                break;
                case EnumRootAction.Type2:
                                switch(child){
                                       case EnumChildAction.Ac1: 
                                                    // DO something
                                                    break;
                                        case EnumChildAction.Ac3: 
                                                    // DO something
                                                    break;
                                        default: // child is not child of type root
                                                return false;
                                }
                                break;
                ... // etc...
                default: 
                    return false;                       
        }
        return true;
     }
```

However, I do believe that it is a bad looking piece of code... :) ... the "consumer" of this service does not know the correct combination of root/child that are valid and might pass a wrong one.

I thought of "spiting" it into several methods, something like: `DoMyThingsForRootType1(EnumChildActionForType1 child)` but in a long term term this is not so easy to change in my case. I explain why: if the signature of my service changes continuously I need to update the service protocol of all my real time clients.... update source code and deploy it again.... and at the present day the client can simply make these changes manually by changing some app.settings values.

At this point I am providing a single sheet of paper with the correct combinations but this is crap as well in my eyes.

Perhaps I am just looking at this from one perspective and somehow I am not being able to expand my horizons... this is why I would like to ear some feedback from you guys/gals...

Is there a better design pattern for this?
At least some kind of way to inform the service's client of the valid combinations....

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with a language. Enums aren't implemented the same way in all languages.

Comment: Both enum swich-case are dependent to each other. In either case you have to add double switch. 

So I think after adding multiple methods for any one case, your code be look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use interfaces or base classes instead of enums you can harness the power of object-orientation to determine how the combinations are to be evaluated. This allows you to group the root/child action functionality in an easy-to-understand and easy-to-maintain way. It is somewhat long-winded however:

```
    public interface IChildAction
    {
    }

    public class ChildAction1 : IChildAction
    {
    }

    public class ChildAction2 : IChildAction
    {
    }

    public class ChildAction3 : IChildAction
    {
    }

    public abstract class BaseRootAction
    {
        public virtual bool Process(ChildAction1 action)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public virtual bool Process(ChildAction2 action)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public virtual bool Process(ChildAction3 action)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class RootAction1 : BaseRootAction
    {
        public override bool Process(ChildAction1 action)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Root action 1, Child action 1");
            return true;
        }

        public override bool Process(ChildAction2 action)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Root action 1, Child action 2");
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class RootAction2 : BaseRootAction
    {
        public override bool Process(ChildAction1 action)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Root action 2, Child action 1");
            return true;
        }

        public override bool Process(ChildAction3 action)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Root action 2, Child action 3");
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class RootAction3 : BaseRootAction
    {
        public override bool Process(ChildAction2 action)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Root action 3, Child action 2");
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool DoMyThings(BaseRootAction rootAction, IChildAction childAction)
    {
        return rootAction.Process((dynamic)childAction);
    }
```

I also include my test method for completeness:

```
    private void Test()
    {
        List<BaseRootAction> rootActions = new List<BaseRootAction>() { new RootAction1(), new RootAction2(), new RootAction3()};
        List<IChildAction> childActions = new List<IChildAction>() { new ChildAction1(), new ChildAction2(), new ChildAction3()};
        foreach (BaseRootAction rootAction in rootActions)
        {
            foreach (IChildAction childAction in childActions)
            {
                bool result = DoMyThings(rootAction, childAction);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Processed '{0}' / '{1}': Result = {2}", rootAction.GetType().Name, childAction.GetType().Name, result));
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need the Enums the action classes can be derived from them, but the solution becomes more bloated.

Comment: Client and server communicate through network i.e inter-process communication. How can client create and pass instance of BaseRootAction and IChildAction to server?

Comment: @Kata WCF can handle serialisable objects: the DataContract requires 'KnownType' to be specified for interfaces and abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

The first step could be that in every case you call a method.

```
case EnumRootAction.Type1:
    switch(child){
        case EnumChildAction.Ac1: 
            Type1_Ac1();
            break;
```

The second step could be that you use a matrix of delegates instead of the function.

```
    delegate bool DoMyThingsAction();
    DoMyThingsAction[,] doMyThings;

    public void InitializeDoMyThings()
    {
        doMyThings = new DoMyThingsAction[10, 10]; // number of actions and type
        doMyThings[0, 0] = Type1_Ac1;
        // and so on
    }
```

To call it you can use

```
    doMyThings[(int)root, (int)child];
```

If you don't like the cast to int in doMyThings call you can use a different structure and override the indexer.

Another option is to use reflection to get the method (I don't like it)

```
public bool DoMyThings(EnumRootAction root, EnumChildAction child){
       return GetType().GetMethod(string.Format("{0}_{1}", root, child).Invoke(this);
}
```

**EDIT**
Looking at your program you should return false if there is not the method.
In case of matrix you can check if there is the function or not before call it, in case of reflection you can check if GetMethod returns null.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the Visitor Pattern. Your `RootAction`s are Visitors and `ChildAction`s are Elements. Here is the code, note how powerful of overloading in OOP:

```
List<RootAction_Visitor> visitors = new List<>();
visitors[EnumRootAction.Type1] = new RootAction1_Visitor();
visitors[EnumRootAction.Type2] = new RootAction2_Visitor();

List<ChildAction_Element> elements = new List<>();
elements[EnumChildAction.Ac1] = new ChildAction1_Element();
elements[EnumChildAction.Ac2] = new ChildAction2_Element();
elements[EnumChildAction.Ac3] = new ChildAction3_Element();

public void doMyThing(EnumRootAction root, EnumChildAction child) {
    elements[child].accept( visitors[root] );
}

//=======================================================================
// Visitors

abstract class RootAction_Visitor {
    public void visit(ChildAction1_Element childAction) { /*.. reject by default ...*/ }
    public void visit(ChildAction2_Element childAction) { /*.. reject by default ...*/ }
    public void visit(ChildAction3_Element childAction) { /*.. reject by default ...*/ }
}

class RootAction1_Visitor : RootAction_Visitor {
    public override void visit(ChildAction1_Element childAction) {
        // ... do something
    }
    public override void visit(ChildAction2_Element childAction) {
        // ... do something
    }
}

class RootAction2_Visitor : RootAction_Visitor {
    public override void visit(ChildAction1_Element childAction1) {
        // ... do something
    }
    public override void visit(ChildAction3_Element childAction3) {
        // ... do something
    }
}

//=======================================================================
// Elements

interface ChildAction_Element {
    void accept(RootAction_Visitor visitor);
}

class ChildAction1_Element : ChildAction_Element {
    public void accept(RootAction_Visitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }
}

class ChildAction2_Element : ChildAction_Element {
    public void accept(RootAction_Visitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }
}

class ChildAction3_Element : ChildAction_Element {
    public void accept(RootAction_Visitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }
}
```

Because your client and server communicate through network (inter-process communication). There's no way to ensure data sent by client is valid, we need to validate the data and reject wrong request. However, you should provide another service so client can know which combinations of actions are correct before requesting to your main service.

P/S: choosing between `RootAction` and `ChildAction`, which is Visitor, which is Element depends on how stable are they. If `RootAction`s are unstable, i.e. new kinds of `RootAction` will come, then they should be `Visitors`.